# Flask Backend - Cors Issue on Render

Tags: python, angular, flask, cors, render

I am building a flask backend service which I currently have it on Render. The backend works fine when I hit the API on Postman or https://reqbin.com/. The problem comes after I include the code on my Angular Project and it throws an error regarding the CORS. Below is my backend CORS part & the errors.

Backend API:

```
cors_config = {
    "origins": "*",
    "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
}

# Enable CORS for all routes
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": cors_config})


# Define API endpoint for updating column value
@app.route('/update_booking/', methods=['PUT', 'OPTIONS'])
def update_booking():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response = jsonify({})
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT')
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
        return response
```

Error on console when trying to reach the backend endpoint:

[image: Error on console when trying to reach the backend endpoint]

PUT in Angular:

```
test1() {
    const payload = {
      "statusid": "2",
      "phoneid": this.getData().data,
      "nameid": this.getData2().data
    };
    fetch('https://ENDPOINT', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => console.log('Update successful:', data))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error updating booking:', error);

      });
    }
```

Any further information on what else is needed? I am a bit frustated here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to apply the same CORS origins on all of the URLs, you may use the `origins` parameter directly.

```py
CORS(app, origins=[“http://localhost:8000”, “https://example.com”])
```

Read more about it here:
https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html#flask_cors.CORS

Comment: Hello, I have tried to put the local host and my URL directly, still giving the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and it was because of back end error, which resulted in CORS error on the front end.